# Get latitude and longitude before the last element

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to get the distance between a whole track , so what I'm trying to do is the following.

First setup a listener that will trigger every lat lang changes, then just get the latest lat lang and get the lat langs before the last one , so I can measure the distance between the last lat lang and the previous one, then I'm planning to put it all into an array to sum it up and have the total distance when I stop my track.

I'm using a linkedlist to save latlangs

```
 mLinkedList.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

 float results[] = new float[10];
                   Location.distanceBetween(needThisLatitude,needThisLongitude,locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude(),locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude(),results);
//Then I will save that results into an array and sum them up to get total distance.
```

Comment: what are you asking exactly? you just described what you did.

Comment: Check out the SphericaUtil.computeLength - it may get you thinking about how to manage your points: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeLength.